# Div контейнер оставляет вокруг себя линии

Tags: html, css

Div контейнер 'Profile' оставляет вокруг себя линии от другого div контейнера, хотя он должен заполняться. Возможно в css не указаны размеры так что вот: `width: 260px, height: 81px`

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7746DE, #4C3480); /* Градиентный фон */
    background-size: cover; /* Это свойство автоматически масштабирует изображение, чтобы оно покрывало всю доступную область */
    background-position: center center; /* Центрирует изображение по горизонтали и вертикали */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Отключает повтор изображения, если оно меньше, чем контейнер */
}

.sidebar {
    width: 250px; /* Ширина сайдбара */
    background-color: #5B3AA2; /* Цвет фона сайдбара */
    height: 100%; /* Занимает всю доступную высоту экрана */
    position: fixed; /* Фиксированное позиционирование, чтобы оставаться видимым при прокрутке */
    top: 0; /* Размещение сверху */
    left: 0; /* Размещение слева */
}

/* Стили для списка навигации */
.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры списка */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

.Profile {
    background-color: #4F338D;
    background-size: cover; /* Это свойство автоматически масштабирует изображение, чтобы оно покрывало всю доступную область */
    background-position: center center; /* Центрирует изображение по горизонтали и вертикали */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Отключает повтор изображения, если оно меньше, чем контейнер */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex; /* Располагаем элементы внутри контейнера в ряд */
    align-items: center; /* Выравниваем элементы по вертикали */
}

p { margin: 0; }

.ChatMemberUsername {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className='sidebar'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {/* <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Выйти</button> */}
          <div className='Profile'>
            <img src={user.photoURL} alt='memberAvatar' style={{border: '5px solid #9AD450', borderRadius: '50%', width: '15%', height: '15%'}}/>
            <div className='ChatMemberUsername' style={{color: copiedUsername ? '#9AD450' : '#fff'}} ref={textRef} onClick={CopyUsername}>{Username}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```